# with_items - combining string properties

Tags: ansible

I want to know if there is a way to combine strings together to make a new item string property for with_items loop.

I've tried:

```
with_items:
        - {first: 'one', second: '{{ item.first}}two'}

with_items:
        - {first: 'one', second: '{{ first}}two'}
```

---

```
  - hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    user: root
    gather_facts: no
    tasks:
    - shell: "echo {{ item.second }}"
      with_items:
        - {first: 'one', second: '{{ item.first}}-two'}
```

item.first = be "one"
item.second = "one-two", taking item.first and adding on to it.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion won't work. Testing recursion is the reason to make it complicated?

Otherwise it would be quite simple.

```
- shell: "echo {{ item.first }}-{{ item.second }}"
  with_items:
    - {first: 'one', second: 'two'}
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this? I need this to specify a directory path that uses the first element of the item list.